# Error in Logic of linked list

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, valgrind

I have written a code for linked list with a head node. I'm having logical errors in **removing** a node and **finding** a node by using its attribute (code) in the list. I tried debugging but it doesn't helped much. I could use some help in finding the errors. Thanks.

**Errors:**

1. I cannot find a product node by its code value.
2. When I try to remove some node, it seems the nodes are non-existent.

My Debugging Output:
For the main program shown here, The result was "NOT FOUND". But the node with a code value "0000" exists.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "products.h"

void print_product(struct product *p)
{
    printf("%s (%s) -- stock: %d, price: %lf\n",
                p->title, p->code,
                p->stock, p->price);
}

int main()
{
    struct product_list list;
    struct product *p;
    init_list(&list);
    add_product(&list, "test", "1234", 1, 0.50);
    add_product(&list, "Product 1", "0000", 0, 10);
    add_product(&list, "Long name, isn't it", "1234567890", 10, 100);
    add_product(&list, "Product 3", "9999999", 0, 20);
    p = find_product(&list, "0000");
    if (p)
        print_product(p);
    else
        printf("Not found\n");
    int i=remove_product(&list, "0000");
    printf("Removed %d items\n", i);
    delete_list(&list);
}
```

**products.h**

```
struct product {
    char *title;  // Name of the product
    char code[8]; // Max. 7 characters of product ID
    int stock;  // Current stock (number of units)
    double price;  // Price of a single unit
    struct product *next; // pointer to next item in linked list
};

struct product_list {
    struct product *head;
    // could have other list specific elements, like length of the list, last update time, etc.
    };

void init_list(struct product_list *list);
struct product *add_product(struct product_list *start, const char *title, const char *code,
        int stock, double price);
struct product *find_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code);
int remove_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code);
int delete_list(struct product_list *start);
```

**products.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "products.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void init_list (struct product_list *list)
{
  list->head = malloc(sizeof(struct product));
}

/* Add product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: start of the linked list
 * title, code, stock, price: to be copied as created structure content
 * 
 * Returns: pointer to the newly added node in the linked list
 */
struct product *add_product(struct product_list *start, const char *title, const char *code,
        int stock, double price) {
    while(start->head->next != NULL){
        start->head = start->head->next;
    }
    if(start->head->title == NULL){
        start->head->title = malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
        strcpy(start->head->title, title);
        strncpy(start->head->code, code, 7);
        start->head->code[7] = 0;
        start->head->stock = stock;
        start->head->price = price;
    }else{
        start->head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct product));
        start->head = start->head->next;
        start->head->title = malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
        strcpy(start->head->title, title);
        strncpy(start->head->code, code, 7);
        start->head->code[7] = 0;
        start->head->stock = stock;
        start->head->price = price;
    }
    return start->head;
}

/* Find product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: The head node
 * code: product code to be found
 * 
 * Returns: Pointer to the first instance of product, or NULL if not found
 */
struct product *find_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code) {
    while(start->head != NULL){
        if (!strcmp(start->head->code, code)) {
            return start->head;
        }else{
            start->head = start->head->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Remove Product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: The head node
 * code: value to be removed
 *
 * Enough to remove first istance, no need to check for dublicates
 *
 * Returns: The number of removed items (0 or 1)
 */
int remove_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code) {
    if (!strcmp(start->head->code, code)) {
        free(start->head->title);
        free(start->head);
        start->head = start->head->next;
        return 1;
    }
    while(start->head->next !=NULL){
        if(!strcmp(start->head->next->code, code)){
            free(start->head->next->title);
            start->head->next = start->head->next->next;
            return 1;
        }else{
            start->head = start->head->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Delete list */
/* Parameters:
 * start: list head
 *
 * Returns: 1, when list has been deleted
 */
int delete_list(struct product_list *listhead) {
    while(listhead->head != NULL){
        free(listhead->head->title);
        listhead->head = listhead->head->next;
    }    
    return 1;
}
```

**UPDATED CODE WITH VALGRIND RESULTS:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct product {
    char *title;  // Name of the product
    char code[8]; // Max. 7 characters of product ID
    int stock;  // Current stock (number of units)
    double price;  // Price of a single unit
    struct product *next; // pointer to next item in linked list
};

struct product_list {
    struct product *head;
    // could have other list specific elements, like length of the list, last update time, etc.
    };

void init_list (struct product_list *list)
{
  list->head = malloc(sizeof(struct product));
}

/* Add product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: start of the linked list
 * title, code, stock, price: to be copied as created structure content
 * 
 * Returns: pointer to the newly added node in the linked list
 */
struct product *add_product(struct product_list *start, const char *title, const char *code,
        int stock, double price) {
    struct product_list *newStart = start;    
    while(newStart->head->next != NULL){
        newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
    }
    if(newStart->head->title == NULL){
        newStart->head->title = malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
        strcpy(newStart->head->title, title);
        strncpy(newStart->head->code, code, 7);
        newStart->head->code[7] = 0;
        newStart->head->stock = stock;
        newStart->head->price = price;
    }else{
        newStart->head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct product));
        newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
        newStart->head->title = malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
        strcpy(newStart->head->title, title);
        strncpy(newStart->head->code, code, 7);
        newStart->head->code[7] = 0;
        newStart->head->stock = stock;
        newStart->head->price = price;
    }
    return newStart->head;
}

/* Find product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: The head node
 * code: product code to be found
 * 
 * Returns: Pointer to the first instance of product, or NULL if not found
 */
struct product *find_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code) {
    struct product_list *newStart = start;
    while(newStart->head != NULL){
        if (!strcmp(newStart->head->code, code)) {
            return newStart->head;
        }else{
            newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Remove Product */
/* Parameters:
 * start: The head node
 * code: value to be removed
 *
 * Enough to remove first istance, no need to check for dublicates
 *
 * Returns: The number of removed items (0 or 1)
 */
int remove_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code) {
    struct product_list *newStart = start;
    if (!strcmp(newStart->head->code, code)) {
        free(newStart->head->title);
        free(newStart->head);
        newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
        return 1;
    }
    while(newStart->head->next !=NULL){
        if(!strcmp(newStart->head->next->code, code)){
            free(newStart->head->next->title);
            newStart->head->next = newStart->head->next->next;
            return 1;
        }else{
            newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Delete list */
/* Parameters:
 * start: list head
 *
 * Returns: 1, when list has been deleted
 */
int delete_list(struct product_list *listhead) {
    while(listhead->head != NULL){
        free(listhead->head->title);
        listhead->head = listhead->head->next;
    }    
    return 1;
}

void print_product(struct product *p)
{
    printf("%s (%s) -- stock: %d, price: %lf\n",
                p->title, p->code,
                p->stock, p->price);
}

int main()
{
    struct product_list list;
    struct product *p;
    init_list(&list);
    add_product(&list, "test", "1234", 1, 0.50);
    add_product(&list, "Product 1", "0000", 0, 10);
    add_product(&list, "Long name, isn't it", "1234567890", 10, 100);
    add_product(&list, "Product 3", "9999999", 0, 20);
    p = find_product(&list, "0000");
    if (p)
        print_product(p);
    else
        printf("Not found\n");
    int i=remove_product(&list, "0000");
    printf("Removed %d items\n", i);
    delete_list(&list);
}
```

**Valgrind Output for the Updated code:**

```
==20484== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20484== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20484== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20484== Command: test
==20484== 
==20484== 
==20484== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20484==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20484==   total heap usage: 31 allocs, 31 frees, 2,001 bytes allocated
==20484== 
==20484== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20484== 
==20484== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20484== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: 'I tried debugging but it doesn't helped much' well, what did you find out?

Comment: When you look for an item in the product list, you should _not_ use the list's head pointer to iterate. Use a local variable whose initial value is the head. Otherwise you will destroy the list. The head pointer should only be updated when nodes are inserted at or removed from the front of the list.

Comment: Same problem occurs in add_product; you are assigning start->head to point to the new entry, an so losing the actual start of your list.

Comment: I have put everything in the new code, with code for the new head node. But Still there is some logical errors. I'm getting the same results as before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? - not doing any debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated code has exactly the same issues:

```
newStart->head = newStart->head->next;
```

newStart is just an alias for the start pointer.

You should be **iterating** on the list, not just updating its head to the next value.

For  example, list

A -> B -> C

will look after your first find iteration like

B -> C

You lost one element at the head by the incorrect assignment.

it should be (for example):

```
struct product *find_product(struct product_list *start, const char *code) {
    struct product_list *elem = start->head;
    while(elem  != NULL){
        if (!strcmp(elem->code, code)) {
            return elem;
        }else{
            elem = elem->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assigning here  effectively eliminating the element from the list :

```
start->head = start->head->next;
```

What you're looking for is probably get some pointer

```
product* current;
product* nextEl = current->next;
```

and iterating on it:

```
while (nextEl != null) {
if (!strcmp(nextEl->code, code))  {
   product* current->next = nextEl->next;
   free (nextEl);
    return 1;
}
else {
   current = nextEl;
   nextEl = nextEl->next;
}

}
 return 0;
```

In general you should avoid to work directly with head pointer, use some local pointer in order to prevent corruption (like in find or add functions)